# Executing a program according to the last modified date

Tags: linux, shell-script, scripting, date

I need to write a script which would execute some executables in a directory according to the last modified date. The oldest should run first. How do I do it?

This is what I have done so far

```
for f in  ./jobqueue/*; #accessing the queue
do 
    chmod +x *  # giving executable permission for the files
    $f  # running the executables
done
```

Comment: This could easily be a huge security hole depending on your environment.  But other than that, it looks like the code you have should work if the files are names using a sequential naming scheme, except that the `chmod` command should be `chmod +x $f` (again, security red flags here).  What specifically is not working as you expect?

Comment: The files are executing, but i need them to execute in the above mentioned order. Which means the oldest should run first

Comment: What determines the file names?  What are the rules and constraints on file names?

Comment: there are no rules. It can be any name. They are complied c programs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided that your filenames don't contain spaces or tabs or newlines or `?` or `*` or `[` and that the directory doesn't contain subdirectories, you might try something like

```
for f in $(ls -tr ./jobqueue/) ; do

  chmod +x ./jobqueue/$f
  ./jobqueue/$f

done
```

Comment: "there are no rules. It can be any name." - OP
I find it ironic that this is the accepted answer, even with all of the filename qualifications.

Answer (score 3):

Shell globbings are expanded in lexical order by default. If you need a different sort order, you'll need a shell that supports specifying the order like `zsh` which is probably a good thing since you're already using `zsh` syntax there (by not quoting `$f`).

```
for f in  ./jobqueue/*(.NOm); do
  chmod +x $f
  $f
done
```

The `(.NOm)` part is `zsh`'s globbing qualifiers. `.` for regular files only, `N` to expand to nothing if there's no matching file instead of reporting an error (as if the `nullglob` option was enabled), `Om` to <kbd>o</kbd>rder (uppercase for reverse order) on <kbd>m</kbd>odification time.

With the GNU shell (`bash`) and with GNU `ls`, the equivalent would be:

```
eval "files=($(ls -drt --quoting-style=shell ./jobqueue/* 2> /dev/null))"
for f in "${files[@]}"
  [ -f "$f" ] && [ ! -L "$f" ] || continue
  chmod +x -- "$f"
  "$f"
done
```

Comment: what does the (NOm) mean

Comment: : syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: @DesirePRG, you missed the part that said `zsh`. It is `zsh` syntax, so you need `zsh` to interpret that script.